# SwipeRefreshLayout icon does not show but callback works

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I have a simple layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/result_list_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/result_list"
            layout="@layout/result_list"/>

        <include layout="@layout/loading_animated_house"/>


    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

When 1st `include` is visible and 2nd gone then all is fine.

When 1st `include` is gone and 2nd is visible then I don't see the loading image.

When pulling just a super fast blink (of the loading image) just before it refreshes but the action did actually run as the callback is called.

Any clues would be helpful thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out some scenarios i noted that:

1) `onInterceptTouchEvent` never returns true and `mIsBeingDragged` is never really set to true, thus later in `onTouchEvent` `moveSpinner` is never called.

2) `onTouchEvent` with `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` gets called which then calls `finishSpinner` and this is why I get the callback.

3) after I perform a network call on response or error i call `swiperefresh.setRefreshing(false);` which is why I got the blinking(`startScaleDownAnimation`) at the end.

So identifying that you need a touchable child to start your drag from,

the solution to that could be simply to set the `FrameLayout` clickable :

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/result_list_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

May use below code,`<include android:id="@+id/result_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" layout="@layout/result_list"/>`

Comment: they both match parent